# In one file its working, in two files I got an error

Tags: javascript, class, import, babeljs

I have the same code but in one way it's working and in other way it's not. When Im putting this code in one file then it's working, but when im using imports with babel then I get an error. Code example:

```
class Mob {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = 100;
  }
  getHealth() {
    return this.health;
  }
  weather() {
    game.setWeather('rainbow');
    console.log(game.weather);
  }

}

class World {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weather = 'rain';
    this.monsters = {};

  }

 addMonster(name) {
   const monster = new Mob(name);
   this.monsters['1'] = monster;
 }

 setWeather(weather) {
   this.weather = weather;
 }
 play() {
   this.addMonster('dragon');
   this.monsters['1'].weather();
 }
}
```

But when I'll separate it to two files like this:

**World.js:**

```
import Mob from './Mob';


export default class World {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.weather = 'rain';
      this.monsters = {};

    }

   addMonster(name) {
     const monster = new Mob(name);
     this.monsters['1'] = monster;
   }

   setWeather(weather) {
     this.weather = weather;
   }
   play() {
     this.addMonster('dragon');
     this.monsters['1'].weather();


   }
  }
```

**Mob.js:**

```
export default class Mob {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.health = 100;
    }
    getHealth() {
      return this.health;
    }
    weather() {
      game.setWeather('rainbow');
      console.log(game.weather);
    }

  }
```

And import it as:

```
import World from './game_manager/World';

const game = new World;
game.play();
```

I've got an error where it says game ( game.setWeather('rainbow') ) is not defined.
How can I fix that if I want to have that code in two separate files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `game` variable is not in scope when you put this class in different file. you need to pass `game` variable in `weather()` function.

Two changes required

in class Mob

```
weather(game) {
   game.setWeather('rainbow');
   console.log(game.weather);
}
```

In class World, add `this` as argument in `weather()` function

```
play() {
  this.addMonster('dragon');
  this.monsters['1'].weather(this);
}
```

```js
class Mob {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.health = 100;
    }
    getHealth() {
      return this.health;
    }
    weather(game) {
      game.setWeather('rainbow');
      console.log(game.weather);
    }

  }




class World {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.weather = 'rain';
      this.monsters = {};

    }

   addMonster(name) {
     const monster = new Mob(name);
     this.monsters['1'] = monster;
   }

   setWeather(weather) {
     this.weather = weather;
   }
   
   play() {
     this.addMonster('dragon');
     this.monsters['1'].weather(this);
   }
  }

const game = new World;
game.play();
```

Comment: When I do that now I've got a different error:
Type error: Cannot read property 'setWeather' of undefined.

Comment: You must have missed the `this` argument in World class paly method. See the updated answer, I added specific part of code above. `this.monsters['1'].weather(this);`, add this here <---